# How to create a loop device without using mount (without loop.ko)?

Tags: linux, mount, fat32

I was trying to do the [following](http://blog.m8t.in/2009/05/making-use-of-loop-devices-on-linux.html):

```
mkdir loop-mount
mount -o loop output loop-mount
```

The problem is that I don't have `loop.ko` and can't add it to my machine.

Is there a tool or other way to create a loop device?

Comment: Why can't you add it ? Why do you want to create a loop device ? you could see if you have `losetup`

Comment: Do you mean you do not have `loop` either as a module or built-in? If so, you're probably SOL.

Comment: I want to have a partition on my mass storage device from a virtual machine I can't connect the device to.

Comment: Without support for loop devices compiled into kernel statically or as a module, there is no way to create a loop device.

Comment: @SamiLaine not true, you can run file system on top on user space, same idea as emulation.

Comment: File system, yes, using FUSE, but a loop device, no.